# Работа со строками, удаление товара из корзины

Tags: javascript, cookie

Пытаюсь реализовать удаление товара из корзины. Корзина реализована так:

В куки carts помещаются через запятую **ID** товаров, пример: 36,37,38

На кнопку удалить товар из корзины висит функция, которая считывает строку ищет число и удаляет его в зависимости от того, в начали он, в конце или середине. Если в начале удаляет число вместе с запятой, если в середине аналогично, а если в конце только число.

**Код функции:**

```
function deletecart(id) {
    var carts = $.cookie("cart");
    if(carts.indexOf(id) == carts.length - 1)
    carts = carts.replace(id, "");
    else
    carts = carts.replace(id + ",", "");
    if(carts.indexOf(",") == -1) {
      carts = null;
    }
    $.cookie("cart", carts);
    getInfoCart();
  }
```

На каждом товаре при указании функции на кнопку удалить посылается ID этого товара.

Все бы ничего, раньше в некоторых проектах с помощью какой-то магии это работало, однако в текущем проекте магия исчезла. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Забудьте уже про куки и используйте [Web_Storage_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: Впервые слышу про эту технологию, спасибо за ссылку, обязательно прочту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, более надёжный способ делать это будет таким:

```js
function deletecart(id) {
    var carts = $.cookie("cart");

    carts = carts.split(',').filter(num => Number(num) !== id).join(',');
    if (carts.length === 0) carts = null;

    $.cookie("cart", carts);
    getInfoCart();
}
```

Меня смутил фрагмент:

```js
   if(carts.indexOf(",") == -1) {
      carts = null;
    }
```

Потому что он почему-то возвращает `null`, если в списке осталось только одно число без разделителя (скажем, было `36,37`, удалили `36,`, осталось `37`). Поэтому я изменил этот фрагмент: теперь `cart` становится `null`, только если в ней вообще не осталось номеров (если строка пустая).